# Unwanted CSS styles in Vite+Vue page

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

In the Vite-Vue application I implemented the styles for both index.html and vue components/views , but browser shows them as crossed out. AMany =styles that I added in component/views are also crossed out.
[image: My browser]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-height: auto;
        color: black;
        background: white;
        transition: none;
        line-height: normal;
        font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-rendering: auto;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How to remove this unwanted styles and stop modyfing my styles in Vite-Vue app?

Comment: search your project... the styles come from a stylesheet somewhere.  try `src/assets/base.css`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yoduh get me advice - I changed files base.css and main.css and it work!

I cleared content main.css and base.css files in assets directory.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you click **here**, chrome or Edge would take you to the source file of this css and you can find which file did that and delete it.
[image]